# how to animate some portion of images?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing fun application.In which i want to animate some area(portion) of images.
I dont know how it possible.If u have any idea then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to animate a portion of an image you could just create a smaller animation and put it at the right relative location inside a larger image.

If you want to know how to animate images in general, that's a different question entirely.